# RoutingOrder does not work

Tags: docusignapi

When I am getting envelope by [RequestStatus](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Status%20and%20Managing%20Group/EnvelopeStatus.htm%3FTocPath%3DDocuSign%2520Service%2520API%2520Information%7CStatus%2520and%2520Managing%2520Function%2520Group%7CEnvelopeStatus%7C_____0) all recipients have same routing number. But I am sure and debug that provided different parameter for each recipient. And all recipients gets email in same time. How can I send envelope for each recipient according to RoutingOrder?

Sequential Signing (API) enabled for my account: 
[image]

My examlple:

```
        WebAPI.Recipient[] recipients = {new WebAPI.Recipient(), new WebAPI.Recipient()};
        recipients[0].Email = "JohnDo@gmail.com";
        recipients[0].UserName = "John Do";
        recipients[0].Type = WebAPI.RecipientTypeCode.Signer;
        recipients[0].ID = "2";
        recipients[0].RoutingOrder = 2;

        recipients[1].Email = "JohnDo2@gmail.com";
        recipients[1].UserName = "John Do2";
        recipients[1].Type = WebAPI.RecipientTypeCode.Signer;
        recipients[1].ID = "1";
        recipients[1].RoutingOrder = 1;

        // Create envelope
        WebAPI.Envelope envelope = new WebAPI.Envelope();
        envelope.Subject = "Subject line mandatory!";
        envelope.Recipients = recipients;
        envelope.AccountId = APIAccountId;

        // Create document
        envelope.Documents = new WebAPI.Document[1];
        WebAPI.Document doc = new WebAPI.Document();
        doc.ID = "1";
        doc.Name = "Picture PDF";
        doc.TransformPdfFields = true;
        doc.PDFBytes = Properties.Resources.test;
        envelope.Documents[0] = doc;

        // Create tab
        WebAPI.Tab tab = new WebAPI.Tab();
        WebAPI.AnchorTab anchorTab = new WebAPI.AnchorTab();
        anchorTab.AnchorTabString = "Adobe";
        anchorTab.IgnoreIfNotPresent = true;
        anchorTab.IgnoreIfNotPresentSpecified = true;
        tab.AnchorTabItem = anchorTab;
        tab.CustomTabRequired = false;
        tab.SenderRequired = false;
        tab.Type = WebAPI.TabTypeCode.SignHere;
        tab.DocumentID = "1";
        tab.RecipientID = "1";

        WebAPI.Tab tab2 = new WebAPI.Tab();
        WebAPI.AnchorTab anchorTab2 = new WebAPI.AnchorTab();
        anchorTab2.AnchorTabString = "CustomTag";
        anchorTab2.IgnoreIfNotPresent = true;
        anchorTab2.IgnoreIfNotPresentSpecified = true;
        tab2.AnchorTabItem = anchorTab2;
        tab2.Type = WebAPI.TabTypeCode.SignHere;
        tab2.DocumentID = "1";
        tab2.RecipientID = "2";
        tab2.SenderRequired = false;
        tab2.SharedTab = true;
        tab2.TabLabel = "CustomTag";
        tab2.Value = "Value2";

        envelope.Tabs = new WebAPI.Tab[2];
        envelope.Tabs[0] = tab;
        envelope.Tabs[1] = tab2;

        // Get results
        WebAPI.EnvelopeStatus status = apiClient.CreateAndSendEnvelope(envelope);
```

**Request to DocuSing SOAP API**: 
[Request to DocuSing SOAP API](http://pastebin.com/FJXizB2b)

Comment: You may want to share your API invocation so we can see how you are constructing the envelope. Some good examples of routingOrder being used available at https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/recipients.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I added my code to header

Comment: Hi Korvinko, looking at the last 5 questions you've asked on Stack Overflow they have all been answered and you have not accepted any of the answers or upvoted anything.  The way this site works is that people ask a technical question, others answer the question, then the asker confirms if the answer works or not.  You need to start doing that if you want people to keep answering your questions...

Comment: Ergin, thank you very much for you clarification. I accepted answers where it was corrected and I will use it information in future.

Comment: I can't see anything off from the code but that's very high level, have you inspected the raw SOAP request (XML) that you are sending out?  Please post that as it should help debug this.  You can use a tool like Fiddler to record it

Comment: Added link to SOAP request in the bottom of my question. So, I see problem, RoutingOrder does not transfer to SOAP. I do know what going on, but I added it in code, you can see example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved by adding option: for RoutingOrderSpecified = true each recipient ;

This code resolve problem for me:

```
        recipients[0].RoutingOrderSpecified = true;
        recipients[1].RoutingOrderSpecified = true;
```

Comment: Great, glad you found this and you can now see why looking at the raw SOAP request can greatly help debugging these issues.  Good thing to know for future issues :)

Comment: Also, one other quick note I'll add- you don't have to specify any of this if using the REST/JSON protocol, which is one of the reason we encourage REST over the older SOAP api...

Comment: Thanks for explain that. It confused me, because it was not specified in DocuSign SOAP Guide.

Comment: Have you seen the DocuSign SOAP SDK up on GitHub?  That has lots of useful code/examples that should help going forward.  For instance, in the C# samples it uses the `RoutingOrderSpecified` parameter:  https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK

Comment: I did not pay attention how it was specified in SDK. Thanks again for you help. I will more careful when will read it.